# Reply Blog Button HTML jQuery append issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a blog which allows users to leave comments and I also want users to reply to those comments. Which means a reply form will need to be generated dynamically and will also need to contain the blog ID so I can write back to the database which comment is associated with.

My list of comments are as follows:

```
    <div class="CommentContainer ClearFix" id="CommentID_1">
    <div class="AuthorImage">
        <img src="/images/uploaded/images/Users/ProfilePicture/Jamie%20Norman.jpg" alt="Jamie Norman">
    </div>
    <div class="CommentDisplay ClearFix">
        <div class="AuthorInformation"><span>Jamie Norman</span> | 9 days ago</div>
        <div class="Comment">Great read, really enjoyed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ControlButtons">
        <a href="#" id="1" class="CommentReply">Reply</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" id="1" class="CommentDelete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="CommentContainer SubCommentContainer ClearFix" id="CommentID_5">
    <div class="AuthorImage SubAuthorImage ClearFix">
        <img src="/images/uploaded/images/Users/ProfilePicture/Edward%20Tucker.jpg" alt="Edward Tucker">
    </div>
    <div class="CommentDisplay SubCommentDisplay ClearFix">
        <div class="AuthorInformation"><span>Edward Tucker</span> | 9 days ago - 5</div>
        <div class="Comment">Agree with what have said here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ControlButtons">
        <a href="#" id="5" class="CommentReply">Reply</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" id="5" class="CommentDelete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="CommentContainer SubCommentContainer ClearFix" id="CommentID_6">
    <div class="AuthorImage SubAuthorImage ClearFix">
        <img src="/images/uploaded/images/Users/ProfilePicture/Jamie%20Norman.jpg" alt="Jamie Norman">
    </div>
    <div class="CommentDisplay SubCommentDisplay ClearFix">
        <div class="AuthorInformation"><span>Jamie Norman</span> | 9 days ago - 6</div>
        <div class="Comment">Thanks</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ControlButtons">
        <a href="#" id="6" class="CommentReply">Reply</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" id="6" class="CommentDelete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="CommentContainer ClearFix" id="CommentID_2">
    <div class="AuthorImage">
        <img src="/images/uploaded/images/Users/ProfilePicture/Millie%20Mitchell.jpg" alt="Millie Mitchell">
    </div>
    <div class="CommentDisplay ClearFix">
        <div class="AuthorInformation"><span>Millie Mitchell</span> | 9 days ago</div>
        <div class="Comment">If only we could all work from home</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ControlButtons">
        <a href="#" id="2" class="CommentReply">Reply</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" id="2" class="CommentDelete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each div block has an id with CommentID_ and the ID of that comment.

What I need is for a div to append after the div in question is closed to show a reply text box and input containing the ID from the parent container. Effectively the ID of the comment being replied to.

In terms of the jQuery I have so far got the following:

```
$(".CommentReply").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var CommentID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('<div class="CommentContainer SubCommentContainer ClearFix"><div class="AuthorImage SubAuthorImage ClearFix"><img src="/images/uploaded/images/Users/ProfilePicture/Jamie%20Norman.jpg" alt="Jamie Norman"></div><div class="CommentDisplay SubCommentDisplay ClearFix"><form name="InputDataForm" method="post" action="/blog/add-comment"><input type="text" name="BlogID_field" id="BlogID_field" vlaue="27"/><textarea name="AuthorComments_field" id="AuthorComments_field">Join the discussion...</textarea></form></div></div>').insertAfter("#CommentID_"+CommentID);     
    });
```

Which kind of works, but can not get the ID to appear in the input and think it is rather clunky...

I want it to work like the following, if you browse to the comments and click reply it creates a reply form, clock again and it removes it.
https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2018/09/loving-hating-the-hamburger-icon/

JSFiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/MarcellusWallis/2at65p3j/

Comment: Please put static links to images in jsfiddle. And you have a bad approach to insert elements. How are you generating comments, from database?

Comment: Static links added the jsfiddle now. I am not sure the best way to approach this to be honest. The comments are saved to a sql database and then pulled out per blog

Comment: First you have figure out to link the comments to each other in db. Then you can build your ui depending on them. Btw, you did not update the link to fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2at65p3j/9/